# How to disable dragged item inside the droppable div after drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I tried to disable draggable to the item when dropped on a div. So once draggable item is dropped on droppable div, it will be unable to be dragged anywhere else.

This is my code so far:

```
$(".div1").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
       ui.draggable({disabled: true});

});
```

I tried `disabled: true` but this didn't work. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: share more code for better result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the class name 'disabled' then in the property of your class set a none.

```
.disabled{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: this one disable the original draggable item instead of the ones that have been dropped inside the divs.

Comment: it's up to you how to use this codes.. you can give this class in what you want..

Comment: please use touch-actions: none also